# Retrieve data from SQLiteDatabase and display it in a new activity

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-listview, data-retrieval

I can populate my `ListView` of items from my `SQLiteDatabase` in `lunch.java`. now I want to click the one item(total 8 items inside the `ListView`) and go to a new activity called `Display.java` and display all the nutrition facts of it.

**AFTER EDITING**

**lunch.java:**

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
    switch(pos)

    {
    case 0 :
        String mealName = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        Cursor cursor = dbopener.getBreakfastDetails(mealName);
        cursor.moveToNext();
        id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(mealName));
        String message = cursor.getString(1)  + "\n" + cursor.getInt(2);
        Intent event1 = new Intent("com.edu.tp.iit.mns.Display");
        event1.putExtra("name", id);
        startActivity(event1);
        break;
```

**Display.java**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvfoodName);     


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        long id = intent.getLongExtra("name", -1);
        if(id == -1){
            return;
        }

        tv.setText(-1); 

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `onItemcClick` you already have the `id` of the element that was clicked, the `id` parameter. Use that to identify the item in your next activity:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {    
    Intent newActivity = new Intent("com.edu.tp.iit.mns.Display");
    newActivity.putExtra("the_key", id);
    startActivity(newActivity);
}
```

Then in your `Display` activity get that long value and get the data from the database corresponding to that `id`:

```
Intent newActivity = getIntent();
long id = newActivity.getLongExtras("the_key", -1);
if (id == -1) {
    //something has gone wrong or the activity is not started by the launch activity
    return
}
//then query the database and get the data corresponding to the item with the id above
```

The above code would work for the case of a `Cursor` based adapter. But you probably use a list based adapter(because of the `getItemAtPosition(pos)` returning a `String` and not a `Cursor`). In this case I would make the `getLunchDetails` method to return the unique `id` of that meal name and pass that to the `Details` activity:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
    String mealName = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    Cursor cursor = dbopener.getLunchDetails(mealName);
    cursor.moveToNext();
    long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("the name of the id column(probably _id"));
    Intent newActivity = new Intent("com.edu.tp.iit.mns.Display");
    newActivity.putExtra("the_key", id);
    startActivity(newActivity);
}
```

Comment: Please don't spam the question. Check your inbox and please remove the first comment you've made here to my answer.